# In Grover and Shor Algorithms 2 registers of qubits are handled at books, but it's really just one seen as 2?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

I found in the literature that we require at least two quantum registers for arithmetics operation.

*Example:* The function  $f(x)=x^2$  is then a unitary evolution of the two registers, in this example I used 2 qubits to store the arguments of $f$ example $|xx\rangle$ and the second, of size 3, to store the values of f example $|yyy\rangle $ the function is:

$|x\rangle |0\rangle \mapsto |x\rangle |x^{2}\bmod 8\rangle$

If i want get $f(2)=2^2$,  then initialize the quantum computer so?

Seen as one single register:

State $\quad$ ---$\quad$ propability

$|xxyyy\rangle $

$|00000\rangle $------ $0$

$|01000\rangle $------ $0$

$|10000\rangle $------ $1$

$|11000\rangle $------ $0$

$\vdots$

$|11111\rangle $------ $0$

Perform the operation whith quantum gates and get the result

State $\quad$ ---$\quad$ propability

$|xxyyy\rangle $

$|10100\rangle $------ $1$

Seen as two  register:

State $\quad$ ---$\quad$ propability$\quad$State $\quad$ ---$\quad$ propability

$|xx\rangle $-----------------------------$|yyy\rangle $

$|00\rangle $------ $0$---------------------$|000\rangle $------ $1$

$|01\rangle $------ $0$---------------------$|001\rangle $------ $0$

$|10\rangle $------ $1$---------------------$|010\rangle $------ $0$

$|11\rangle $------ $0$---------------------$|011\rangle $------ $0$

---------------------------------------$\vdots$

-----------------------------------$|111\rangle $------ $0$

Perform the operation whith quantum gates and get the result

State $\quad$ ---$\quad$ propability$\quad$State $\quad$ ---$\quad$ propability

$|xx\rangle $-----------------------------$|yyy\rangle $

$|10\rangle $------ $1$---------------------$|100\rangle $------ $1$

Which of the two is  the correct implementation in a quantum computer?